# How to know the speed of USB device connected?

Tags: windows, usb, linux-device-driver, device-driver

Is there any information field or descriptor available to get the speed of a USB device (low speed or full speed or high speed)?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [libusb](http://libusb.info) and running the [libusb_get_device_speed](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__dev.html#ga58c4e448ecd5cd4782f2b896ec40b22b) command.